# How to clear the eshell

Tags: eshell

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733668/command-to-clear-shell-while-using-emacs-shell) I find it hard to believe there is no way to clear the eShell.

Does anybody know of a short function or method to delete the entire buffer. Pressing `C-l` just scrolls the text, as soon as enter is pressed all of that text comes back.

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

Running clear with 1, as in `clear 1` works.

[image]

---

How could you have found this out? We know we want to look for a function about eshell and it has to do with clear. So, why not do `C-h f` and type `eshell clear`. This produces two functions:

1. `eshell/clear-scrollback`
2. `eshell/clear`

If we select `eshell-scrollback`, Emacs shows us usage:

```
eshell/clear-scrollback is a compiled Lisp function in ‘esh-mode.el’.

(eshell/clear-scrollback)

Clear the scrollback content of the eshell window.
```

We try running `eshell/clear-scrollback` and it clears the screen. Ok, we can look at it's implementation but before that let's look at the other function `eshell/clear`. When we select that after `C-h f` and `eshell clear`, we get:

```
eshell/clear is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘esh-mode.el’.

(eshell/clear &optional SCROLLBACK)

Scroll contents of eshell window out of sight, leaving a blank window.
If SCROLLBACK is non-nil, clear the scrollback contents.
```

This tells us that we could run `clear 1` to clear the screen. But, why are there two functions? If we look at the implementation of `eshell/clear`, we can see that the other function is actually used in it. To find the implementation simply click on the `esh-mode.el` in the usage buffer of `eshell/clear`.

```lisp
(defun eshell/clear (&optional scrollback)
  "Scroll contents of eshell window out of sight, leaving a blank window.
If SCROLLBACK is non-nil, clear the scrollback contents."
  (interactive)
  (if scrollback
      (eshell/clear-scrollback)
    (insert (make-string (window-size) ?\n))
    (eshell-send-input)))
```

You can see that at the end this function sends any input which was present at the time of clearing the screen. To get around it, I wrote this little function:

```lisp
(defun run-this-in-eshell (cmd)
  "Runs the command 'cmd' in eshell."
  (with-current-buffer "*eshell*"
    (end-of-buffer)
    (eshell-kill-input)
    (message (concat "Running in Eshell: " cmd))
    (insert cmd)
    (eshell-send-input)
    (end-of-buffer)
    (eshell-bol)
    (yank)))
```

The benefits of this function are that if you put it in a lambda function and bind it to a key like this:

```lisp
(bind-keys*
    ("C-<backspace>" . (lambda () ; clear shell
                     (interactive)
                     (run-this-in-eshell "clear 1"))))
```

It will first kill the current input, run `clear 1` and then yank the input back. This way you can also clear eshell from any other buffer using the keybinding.

Some other functions provided will wipe out any buffer they are ran in. So if you used the keybinding to clear eshell from some other buffer, it will instead clear THAT buffer.

Comment: This is so good! Solid answer, then a thorough walk through of how to do this type of digging and reasoning yourself. Thank you for the education!

Comment: Is there a simple way to add an `eshell-mode-hook` local binding without the need for your function? Tobias' answer didn't work for me. I can't figure out how to pass `eshell/clear` the non-nil argument. When I try to use `eshell/clear-scrollback` as the command, I get a "wrong type argument commandp" error.
 
`(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'eshell/clear-scrollback)))`

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you're trying to do here. Do you just want to bind a lambda to a key that sends eshell a "clear 1" command? Your usage of a hook to add a key binding looks funny, I am not sure if people use hooks that way, but I am no expert. I use the use-package library for all things I can.

Comment: I got the syntax [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Binding-keys-to-commands.html). I'm not sure I want to "send input", rather I'd like to call the eshell command `clear` with the argument `1` or call `eshell/clear-scrollback`. The difference as I understand it: Sending input would mean entering the command as if it were typed in the shell. Calling the command would be equivalent to `M-x clear 1` or `M-x clear-scrollback`.

Comment: I might be wrong now but I think you are confusing the fact that eshell is emacs' shell! So sending it input is the same as calling a function like `M-x <function-name>`, e. g., `M-x magit` does the same thing as `obla/di/da $ magit` in eshell. You can even do `obla/di/da $ (message "Peace")` and it will display "Peace" in the mini-buffer.

Comment: You might try something like this: `(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "C-l") (eshell/clear 1))))`

Comment: Exemplary answer, I wish I could upvote more.

Comment: What was wrong with the `eshell/clear` function that needed writing your own?

Answer (score 11):

There is a function in the current development version, as you can see on the [emacs-devel mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-03/msg00176.html).

The function is very simple:

```el
(defun eshell/clear ()
  "Clear the eshell buffer."
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (erase-buffer)
    (eshell-send-input)))
```

Typing `clear` in eshell will then result in clearing the buffer.

Comment: oh wow. how will i know when this is available in a main release?

Comment: You don't need to wait for the next release.  You can just add this definition to your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file.  You will know that it's available by checking for its definition with `C-h f eshell/clear RET`.

Comment: I am using an older version of Emacs which did not require `(eshell-send-input)` -- that line of code created an extra command prompt.

Answer (score 5):

This does it to one, insted of two lines.

```el
;Clear the eshell buffer.
(defun eshell/clear ()      
   (let ((eshell-buffer-maximum-lines 0)) (eshell-truncate-buffer)))
```

Typing `clear` in eshell will then result in clearing the buffer.

Comment: Whoever left a demerit (downvote) without leaving a helpful constructive comment, please don't do that again -- especially when you see a newcomber to this forum!  I am an intermediate Emacs user and I shouldn't have to sit here scratching my head to try and figure out why this answer received a downvote!  It should not be necessary for me to try out the answer to *maybe* figure out why it was downvoted!

Comment: If you add `(interactive)` after the defun declaration, all works as expected.

Comment: Slightly better then default, clear, which doesn't seem to really clear.

Answer (score 3):

While there *is* a built-in `eshell/clear` in recent versions of Emacs, it does something rather unfortunate: when there is unsent input at the current prompt, clearing the buffer sends the input. This can be problematic if the user has entered partial input.

The following version will clear the buffer while preserving unsent input. This is more `comint`-like.

```el
(defun my/eshell/clear ()
  "Clear `eshell' buffer.

Similar to the behavior of `comint-clear-buffer' in `shell'."
  (interactive)
  (let ((input (eshell-get-old-input)))
    (eshell/clear-scrollback)
    (eshell-emit-prompt)
    (insert input)))
```

You can then bind `C-c M-o` to that function by adding the following to you configuration. Recall that `C-c M-o` is bound to `comint-clear-buffer` in `shell-mode-map` so it will be easier for you to remember it.

```el
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (define-key eshell-mode-map "\C-c\ \M-o" 'my/eshell/clear)))
```

Answer (score 3):

I use make eshell buffers and I rename them accordingly. So a slight modification to @scribe's answer works perfectly on eshell buffers with anyname.

```lisp
(defun run-this-in-eshell (cmd)
    "Runs the command 'cmd' in eshell."
    (end-of-buffer)
    (eshell-kill-input)
    (message (concat "Running in Eshell: " cmd))
    (insert cmd)
    (eshell-send-input)
    (end-of-buffer)
    (eshell-bol)
    (yank))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda () 
    (interactive) 
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-l") 
    (run-this-in-eshell "clear 1"))))
```

Comment: +1 This also works with the latest Emacs that may rename Eshell buffers per project.

Answer (score 1):

The doc string of `eshell/clear` says:

> (eshell/clear &optional SCROLLBACK)
>
> Scroll contents of eshell window out of sight, leaving a blank window.
>   If SCROLLBACK is non-nil, clear the scrollback contents.

So call `clear t` on the Eshell prompt to clear all Eshell buffer contents.

For binding of the command to a key you can use something like the following in `eshell-mode-hook`:

```el
(local-set-key (kbd "C-<backspace>") (lambda () (interactive) (eshell/clear 1)))
```

---

This answer is similar to [scribe's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/54435/2370) and I initially wanted just to comment that one. But, then I thought that this answer goes a bit further. It also gives you a hint on how to use Eshell commands and how to discover their comments yourself.

Comment: I updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

A version of @scribe's code with no helper functions, no debug messages, improved compatibility with per-project Eshell buffers in Emacs 29+, lazy initialization on load, a more standard keyboard shortcut, and fixed clearing with no input:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load 'esh-mode
  (keymap-set eshell-mode-map "C-l"
              (lambda ()
                (interactive)
                (let ((has-input (> (point) eshell-last-output-end)))
                  (when has-input
                    (end-of-buffer)
                    (eshell-kill-input))
                  (insert "clear 1")
                  (eshell-send-input)
                  (when has-input
                    (end-of-buffer)
                    (eshell-bol)
                    (yank))))))
```