# How do I remove Welcome message and function message when sourcing

Tags: eshell

I am learning Emacs and I would like to know how to get rid of the Emacs *Welcome to the Emacs shell* and *eshell/clear* messages when I open a new eshell.

I used [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43622/emacs-start-with-eshell-focused-using-emacs-config-file) question to start an `eshell` at startup and [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12503/how-to-clear-the-eshell) question to add a clear command similar to that of Terminal. In my `.zshrc` I add a file called `.hushlogin` to mute the default message.

Now I would like for when I boot up Emacs, the two messages that print at the beginning of an **eshell** buffer to not appear.

I noticed when I source my init file, all of the functions print as well.

This is a screenshot of what appears any time I create a new eshell
[image]

My .emacs file is below if that helps as well

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes '(tango-dark))
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(markdown-command "/usr/local/bin/pandoc")
 '(package-selected-packages '(pandoc markdown-mode)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(setq default-directory "~/")
(setq command-line-default-directory "~/")

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(package-initialize)

(setq markdown-split-window-direction 'right)

;Start new Emacs window with eshell
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'eshell)
```

This is my `eshell-rc-script` as well if that helps

```
alias emacs 'find-file $1'

#Clear the eshell buffer.
(defun eshell/clear ()
       (let ((eshell-buffer-maximum-lines 0)) (eshell-truncate-buffer)))
```

Comment: Customize `eshell-banner-message` to get rid of the Welcome message.

Comment: Ok, I can see how I customize that. Thanks! Any idea how to get rid of the function names printing when sourcing a file?

Comment: That's the return value of the `defun` form.  Just like entering `(+ 1 2)` prints the return value `3`, entering `(defun foo ...)` prints the return value `foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this that will easily get the results I want. By simply inserting a call to the clear function in my `eshell-rc-script` to run the command right after, it will clear the screen and both messages no longer appear. The line I added was

```
eshell/clear
```

Answer (score 0):

In Emacs 29.1, you can set the opening message to a blank string with `(setq eshell-banner-message "")`.